# Value of sigset_t after sigprocmask

Tags: c, signals, sigprocmask

From `man sigprocmask`:

> "If oset is not null, it is set to the previous value of the signal mask."

My questions:
Without running or debugging the program,

1. After executing line 10, the value of the old signal mask is stored into `y`. Since there were no blocked signals before this line was executed, what is the value of `y`?
2. Is there a way to determine the value of `z` after executing line 14?

```
1 void my_sig_handler(int sig){
2     write(1, "a", 1);
3 }
4 int main(){
5     signal(SIGINT, my_sig_handler);
6     sigset_t x, y, z;
7     sigemptyset(&x);
8     sigaddset(&x, SIGINT);
9
10    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &x, &y);
11    write(1,"1",1);
12    do_some_work();
13    write(1,"2",1);
14    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &y, &z);
15
16    exit(0);
17 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test membership in a signal set with `sigismember`. Historically POSIX omitted a way to identify the range of values that might be signal numbers that you need to test, but all historical systems have `_NSIG` or `NSIG` defined to tell you this, and future POSIX is adding it.

Note that you can't in general assume `y` is empty after line 10, since signal mask is inherited across `fork`/`exec`. Your program may have been started with some signals masked.